# Appsync Amplify - using jwt token

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync

[1] I'm using appsync with Amplify.
I already have a jwt token returned from a backend service. I need to use this token for my appsync requests.

Need suggestions / pointers on how to integrate an already existing jwt token with Amplify.

[2] Also, looks like there are couple of ways to use appsync with nodejs.

- Directly using the appsync client (from 'aws-appsync') and
- Integrating with amplify (from 'aws-amplify')

Can either one of these be used ? What is the difference between the above two modules ?

Comment: What service does your JWT come from?